# Possible to move <menu <item android:onClick=method>> to different class?

Tags: android, methods, onclick, oncreate

My Main activity class contains the onCreate(Bundle), onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) methods, and ALL of my android:onClick= methods (there are many).

I would like to reduce the number of methods in my Main activity class, if possible. So "Is it possible to move my onClick methods to a different class"?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a different class that implements `View.OnClickListener`. Then in the main activity code you can use `setOnClickListener` on the components you want to move the click listener of and give the class that implements `View.OnClickListener` as the parameter.

EDIT: Here is a link to the `View.OnClickListener` page on the Android developer website http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via code only, not XML. You will need to create a class e.g. "ClickManager" where you define OnClickListeners for each button you have within layout.